# Normals look different from Edit and Object modes

Tags: faces, normals

Face orientation is different from Edit mode and Object mode. In object mode, they are all red. In Edit mode, they are correct. How to resolve this issue? Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us your modifiers?

Comment: It is uploaded to the original post. :D

Comment: You have 'Flip Normals' checked in your Solidify modifier. Is that it?

Comment: OMGoodness, I do! Thanks! I did not even know i did that. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked "Flip Normals" under Solidify Monifier. Thanks for Robin Betts pointed out.